# This code doesn't seem to work in ASP.NET MVC2 ... what is it's equivalent, please?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

i have this code which I doesn't seem to work in my copy of VS2010 B2 / VS2010 RC.

```
var areaName = controllerContext.RouteData.GetAreaName();
```

(originally [sourced from here](http://dimebrain.com/2009/11/a-themes-engine-for-asp-net-mvc-2.html)).

Now, it's dealing with Area's, so it's definately MVC 2 stuff.

The error message is that the method `GetAreaName()` doesn't exist.

Does anyone know the proper code to use, instead?

Answer (score 0):

This could be work

> ```
> RouteData.DataTokens["area"];
> ```